# Why can I not set part equal to 'contentDetails' instead of 'snippet' for a PlaylistItems Insert method call?

Tags: python, youtube-api

I am very new to the YouTube API and am quite confused with the difference between the part and body of the API requests and what they mean. On the [YouTube API PlaylistItems Insert documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert) it mentions that it takes `contentDetails`, `id`, `snippet`, and `status` as headers. The following code used to insert a video into a playlist works fine:

```
import os
import pickle
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

credentials = None

# token.pickle stores the user's credentials from previously successful logins
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    print('Loading Credentials From File...')
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        credentials = pickle.load(token)

# If there are no valid credentials available, then either refresh the token or log in.
if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
    if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
        print("Refreshing Access Token...")
        credentials.refresh(Request())
    else:
        print("Fetching New Tokens...")
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'client_secrets.json',
            scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube']
        )

        flow.run_local_server(port=8080, prompt='consent', authorization_prompt_message='')
        credentials = flow.credentials

        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as f:
            print("Saving Credentials for Future Use...")
            pickle.dump(credentials, f)

load_dotenv()
API_KEY = os.getenv('API_KEY')

with build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials) as ytService:
    request = ytService.playlistItems().insert(
        part='snippet',
        body={
            'snippet': {
                'playlistId': 'PLL_zqGJzFipIjbeZfTmJTgnoM4Gl-80Hn',
                'resourceId': {
                    'kind': 'youtube#video',
                    'videoId': 'PhPqP2qUHdg'
                }
            }
        }
        )
    response = request.execute()
    print(response)
```

However, changing `part='snippet'` to `part='contentDetails'` produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Documents\Programming Projects\Google YouTube API\main.py", line 52, in <module>
    response = request.execute()
  File "D:\Documents\Programming Projects\Google YouTube API\.venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Documents\Programming Projects\Google YouTube API\.venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 938, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&alt=json returned "'snippet'". Details: "[{'message': "'snippet'", 'domain': 'youtube.part', 'reason': 'unexpectedPart', 'location': 'part', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

To make YouTube Data API v3 happy with your `contentDetails`, you have to precise both `snippet` and `contentDetails` for `part` as documented by [PlaylistItems: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert):

> [**part**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert#part)
>
> **string**
>
> The **part** parameter serves two purposes in this operation. It identifies the properties that the write operation will set as well as the properties that the API response will include.
>
> The following list contains the **part** names that you can include in the
> parameter value:
>
> - **contentDetails**
> - **id**
> - **snippet**
> - **status**

> **[Request body](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert#request-body)**
>
> Provide a [playlistItem
> resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource)
> in the request body. For that resource:
>
> You must specify a value for these properties:
>
> `snippet.playlistId`
> `snippet.resourceId`
>
> You can set values for these properties:
>
> `snippet.playlistId`
> `snippet.position`
> `snippet.resourceId`
> `contentDetails.note`
> `contentDetails.startAt`
> `contentDetails.endAt`

Here is how you should do it:

```
    request = ytService.playlistItems().insert(
        part='snippet,contentDetails',
        body={
            'snippet': {
                'playlistId': 'PLL_zqGJzFipIjbeZfTmJTgnoM4Gl-80Hn',
                'resourceId': {
                    'kind': 'youtube#video',
                    'videoId': 'PhPqP2qUHdg'
                }
            },
            'contentDetails': {
                'note': 'Here is a user-generated note for this item.'
            }
        }
    )
```

In my opinion `contentDetails` for `PlaylistItems: insert` is useless as [`contentDetails.startAt`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#contentDetails.startAt) and [`contentDetails.endAt`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#contentDetails.endAt) are deprecated and as I am unable to retrieve [`contentDetails.note`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#contentDetails.note) from the YouTube UI nor with [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) with `part=contentDetails` even if being authenticated for both.

Comment: So for any API call I make, I will need to set the parts and then specify the details of each part in the body? If so, the doc mentions that contentDetails, id, snippet and status can all be used but would only snippet be useful as the others don't have body features/are deprecated? What purpose do the part and body serve in the API call? In the docs it's says "the part parameter serves two purposes in this operation. It identifies the properties that the write operation will set as well as the properties that the API response will include". I am not sure what this means.

Comment: As I said in my opinion only `snippet` is useful. Just remember that when providing in the body `X` (such as `snippet` or `contentDetails`), then precise `X` in the part.

Comment: I see, so what does the doc mean when it says "the part parameter serves two purposes in this operation. It identifies the properties that the write operation will set as well as the properties that the API response will include"?